# Flutter giving Firebase Core error on build

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have been building an app in flutter and I have had no problems. Last night I updated Android studio and When I try to do my build in IntelliJ I get the follow error.

```
Initializing gradle...                                              2.9s
Resolving dependencies...                                           7.9s
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Note: /Users/Brandon/Desktop/Programming/DEV/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.                    
Note: /Users/Brandon/Desktop/Programming/DEV/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.                      
Note: /Users/Brandon/Desktop/Programming/DEV/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.4.0+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FirebaseCorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.                      
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.                
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.                    
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      63.1s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

I have changed nothing except the Android Studio update which I would not think to get this results and any insight would be great

Comment: Try Using older Version ->


implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6' -
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'

Comment: This did not work.

Comment: The error went away, but now it just says
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Comment: try adding in gradle - > lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
}

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting the same errors